# Drag button called view whats wrong and how to solve it

Tags: java, android, android-studio, drag-and-drop, draggable

Hi guys can plz help me in this case 
i want to drag a button called view ,
i set up the code like u see down there , but i still can't drag it , can u give me diffident solutions plz with a good explication

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Timer _timer = new Timer();

    private LinearLayout linear1;
    private Button view;
    private Button btn2;
    private Button widgets;
    private TextView textview1;

    private TimerTask mm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(_savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initialize();
        initializeLogic();
    }

    private void initialize() {

        linear1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);
        view = (Button) findViewById(R.id.view);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        widgets = (Button) findViewById(R.id.widgets);
        textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                view.setOnDragListener( new View.OnDragListener() {
                    PointF DownPT = new PointF();
                    PointF StartPT = new PointF();
                    @Override public boolean onDrag(View v, android.view.DragEvent event) {
                        int dragEvent = event.getAction();
                        switch (dragEvent) {
                            case android.view.DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED :
                            DownPT.x = event.getX();
                            DownPT.y = event.getY();
                            StartPT = new PointF( view.getX(), view.getY() ); break;

                            case android.view.DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION :
                            PointF mv = new PointF( event.getX() - DownPT.x, event.getY() - DownPT.y);
                            view.setX((int)(StartPT.x+mv.x)); view.setY((int)(StartPT.y+mv.y));
                            StartPT = new PointF( view.getX(), view.getY() ); break;

                            case android.view.DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED :

                            case android.view.DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :
                            break;
                            case android.view.DragEvent.ACTION_DROP : break;
                            default : break;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

i need a good explication guys , cause  i need to understand the problem , thank u for taking time to help me !
and i need to know whats the different
solution to fix this problem guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement this outside the onClick method :-

```
  view.setOnDragListener( new View.OnDragListener() {
                PointF DownPT = new PointF();
                PointF StartPT = new PointF();
                @Override public boolean onDrag(View v, android.view.DragEvent event) {
                    int dragEvent = event.getAction();
                    switch (dragEvent) {
                        case android.view.DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED :
                        DownPT.x = event.getX();
                        DownPT.y = event.getY();
                        StartPT = new PointF( view.getX(), view.getY() ); break;

                        case android.view.DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION :
                        PointF mv = new PointF( event.getX() - DownPT.x, event.getY() - DownPT.y);
                        view.setX((int)(StartPT.x+mv.x)); view.setY((int)(StartPT.y+mv.y));
                        StartPT = new PointF( view.getX(), view.getY() ); break;

                        case android.view.DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED :

                        case android.view.DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :
                        break;
                        case android.view.DragEvent.ACTION_DROP : break;
                        default : break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Not inside the onClick(). Hope this helps.

Comment: ty for ur help , can i ask u another questions plz

Comment: other than put it outside

Comment: yes you can use the onTouchListener and try it's working.

Comment: oh ty for ur help

Comment: you have to put it outside as it will only work when you click it, only then it would start to move. if you put it outside then you can readily drag the button.